# What MySQL field should I use for a Yes/No Checkbox value?

Tags: mysql, html

I am using the MySQL table below.  I would like to add a field called `'subcheck'` that will be a yes/no value determined by the HTML form input `TYPE = CHECKBOX`.  What "type" should I give this new field?

Thanks in advance,

John

```
`submission` (
  `submissionid` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `loginid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `url` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `displayurl` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
  `datesubmitted` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`submissionid`)
)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a `TINYINT(1)` (BOOL/BOOLEAN is just an [alias](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html) for `TINYINT(1)`).

Another option is to store `Y/N` in a `CHAR(1)`.

I would recommend `TINYINT(1)` as it would give you best portability options.

Answer (score 3):

a boolean - 1 for yes, 0 for no.

(value of the checkbox will need to be 1 or 0 of course).

Much more portable than yes/no imo. efficient too

Answer (score 2):

I personally prefer a enum or set data type in MySQL for this. It keeps the data legible.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend a `TINYINT(1)` for this purpose. It stores either `1` or `0`, to indicate yes or no. It takes very little space and is better supported across different SQL-engines than regular bool-types.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `numeric(1) not null default 0` wherein `0` indicates `false` and `1` indicates `true`.